# Is it safe to store power armor outside of Home Plate?

Tags: fallout-4

In Fallout 4, is it safe to store Power Armor on the power armor station outside of Home Plate in Diamond City?

[image: The power armor station outside the door of Home Plate]

I know that things (including power armor) that's store *inside* of Home Plate is safe from NPCs making off with it. I also know that the crafting stations outside of Home Plate aren't hooked up to the workbench inside. If I leave my armor on this power armor station, is it guaranteed to still be there when I return? Or will it potentially despawn or have an NPC/resident/security wander off with it?

Comment: I've sat my power armor in the past at this exact location for decoration, and it lasted for at least 7 days in real time (don't know how much time has passed in game during that time), at some point I ended up using the power armor again and forget about decoration. So... they *probably* won't disappear by any means, but I'm not completely sure, hence comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Fallout 4 it is a bad idea to leave power armor at a location where it can be accessed by other NPCs. Both in your settlements and in the open world power armor can be taken by idling NPCs or worse, hostile NPCs. This can occur regardless of whether your armor is left free-standing or attached to a power armor station.

There is a way to safely abandon power armor though. **Remove the fusion core**. A fusion core is required to operate a set of power armor and (almost all) NPCs do not spawn with one in their inventory. If you store your power armor here, or anywhere else, you can rest assured that it will not be stolen *as long as you remove the armor's fusion core*.

Edit to address comments: Some searching on the internet suggests that power armor frames do not ever depsawn, and alleged instances of it despawning are actually instances of the frame being stolen by NPCs. With that said, people seem to think the exterior cells (such as Diamond City) reset after 30 days in game time, causing dropped items to disappear. If you visit more frequently than that there will be 0 risk of any changes of any items left behind. The power armor shouldn't despawn regardless, but visiting once a month is an easy way to restart the cell reset clock and alleviate such fears.

Comment: Ahh. That might explain why my power armor hasn't been stolen. If I remember correctly I've used fusion core for gatling laser, so that made the NPCs couldn't access my power armor.

Comment: Yes, minus the fusion core, the NPCs won't run off with it even in settlements. I'm really concerned about the armor itself despawning. (Similar to how if you leave stuff in a random container, it'll usually disappear eventually.)

Comment: Please consider updating your post to clarify this question

Comment: Would you like me to bold the `Or will it potentially despawn` bit? I thought the last sentence was rather clear. :)

Comment: You're good. I'm just not capable of literacy I suppose

Comment: *Take Your Cores* "Automatically yank Fusion Cores out of power armor when you get out."https://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/14773/?

Comment: I never ever had an issue with NPCs taking my Power Armors. I always take out the fusion core before leaving the place. In my longest playthrough I had 15-20 Power Armors of all kinds in Sancturary and not a single one got robbed although I had more than 20 NPCs in Sanctuary.